Python / Selenium / website scrubbing / element is not clickable
On the website i ma trying to click the next button. This is the html code
<a aria-current="page" href="/huuraanbod?query=Amsterdam&amp;page=2&amp;price=1000-1500&amp;range=10&amp;type=appartement&amp;seniorservice=false&amp;view=list&amp;propertyToggle=false" class="active active-exact pagination__arrow pagination__next icon-caret-right">Volgende</a>

Approach 1:
next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'pagination__next')]")))
next_button.click()

Approach 2:
next_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'page=2')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
next_button.click()

`
Either way I am getting the element is not clickable error:
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (781, 5231)

Any thoughts?

Can you share the URL for the page that you're trying to scrape?

sometimes that'll happen when you get an element while the DOM is still loading.  Easy fix is to use a sleep before trying to click it.  Otherwise you can catch the click intercepted exception and re-get the element reference.
